# jekyll server error no such file or directory @ rb_sysopen

Tags: jekyll

> Operate System：**windows 8.1**
>   Jekyll version: **jekyll 2.5.0**
>   python version: **2.7.8**
>   gem -v: **2.2.2**

When I run **jekyll server** output:

```
jekyll 2.5.0 | Error:  No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - D:/GitHub/kanlei.github.com/GitHub/kanlei.github.com/404.html
```

*Detail*

> Configuration file: D:/GitHub/kanlei.github.com/_config.yml
>               Source: D:/GitHub/kanlei.github.com
>          Destination: D:/GitHub/kanlei.github.com/_site
>         Generating...

```
Error reading file D:/GitHub/kanlei.github.com/_layouts/default.html: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - D:/GitHub/kanlei.github.com/GitHub/kanlei.github.com/_layouts/default.html

Error reading file D:/GitHub/kanlei.github.com/_layouts/page.html: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - D:/GitHub/kanlei.github.com/GitHub/kanlei.github.com/_layouts/page.html

Error reading file D:/GitHub/kanlei.github.com/_layouts/post.html: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - D:/GitHub/kanlei.github.com/GitHub/kanlei.github.com/_layouts/post.html

Error reading file D:/GitHub/kanlei.github.com/_posts/core-samples/2011-12-29-jekyll-introduction.md: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - D:/GitHub/kanlei.github.com/GitHub/kanlei.github.com/_posts/core-samples/2011-12-29-jekyll-introduction.md
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the same error. Seems that jekyll 2.5.0 is not compatible with all the others.

Try running this

```
gem uninstall jekyll

gem install  jekyll -v 2.4.0
```

and then build the site again

This method worked for me

Comment: Is this a Windows-specific issue then? 2.5.0 seems to work fine on Linux.

Comment: I run into this running Jekyll 3.0.1 on Windows 7. I changed the destination directory and it worked. - jekyll serve -d e:/new/destination

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem, and been looking for solution, but it seems that it is a problem
with the 2.5.0 version of jekyll, for Windows specifically. I think.

There's already been an issue reported at:
https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/3068

For now, the only workaround i can find is downgrading to jekyll 2.4.0
just as namam posted.

And wait for a fix or a better workaround for 2.5.0

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how this happened, but somehow a file named `127.0.0.1` got created in my Jekyll website repo root directory. My errors were these:

> jekyll 3.9.0 | Error:  No such device or address @ rb_sysopen - /home/username/GS/dev/ElectricRCAircraftGuy.github.io/127.0.0.1

and

> /home/username/gems/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/utils.rb:146:in `initialize': No such device or address @ rb_sysopen - /home/username/GS/dev/ElectricRCAircraftGuy.github.io/127.0.0.1 (Errno::ENXIO)

Full output:

```
~/GS/dev/ElectricRCAircraftGuy.github.io$ ./run_build_site.sh 
Configuration file: /home/username/GS/dev/ElectricRCAircraftGuy.github.io/_config.yml
            Source: /home/username/GS/dev/ElectricRCAircraftGuy.github.io
       Destination: /home/username/GS/dev/ElectricRCAircraftGuy.github.io/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating... 
      Remote Theme: Using theme mmistakes/minimal-mistakes
jekyll 3.9.0 | Error:  No such device or address @ rb_sysopen - /home/username/GS/dev/ElectricRCAircraftGuy.github.io/127.0.0.1
Traceback (most recent call last):
    23: from /home/username/gems/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
    22: from /home/username/gems/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
    21: from /home/username/gems/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/exe/jekyll:15:in `<top (required)>'
    20: from /home/username/gems/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary.rb:19:in `program'
    19: from /home/username/gems/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/program.rb:42:in `go'
    18: from /home/username/gems/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `execute'
    17: from /home/username/gems/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `each'
    16: from /home/username/gems/gems/mercenary-0.3.6/lib/mercenary/command.rb:220:in `block in execute'
    15: from /home/username/gems/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:75:in `block (2 levels) in init_with_program'
    14: from /home/username/gems/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:93:in `start'
    13: from /home/username/gems/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:93:in `each'
    12: from /home/username/gems/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/commands/serve.rb:93:in `block in start'
    11: from /home/username/gems/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:36:in `process'
    10: from /home/username/gems/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/commands/build.rb:65:in `build'
     9: from /home/username/gems/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/command.rb:28:in `process_site'
     8: from /home/username/gems/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:69:in `process'
     7: from /home/username/gems/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/site.rb:164:in `read'
     6: from /home/username/gems/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/reader.rb:16:in `read'
     5: from /home/username/gems/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/reader.rb:45:in `read_directories'
     4: from /home/username/gems/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/reader.rb:45:in `select'
     3: from /home/username/gems/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/reader.rb:46:in `block in read_directories'
     2: from /home/username/gems/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/utils.rb:146:in `has_yaml_header?'
     1: from /home/username/gems/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/utils.rb:146:in `open'
/home/username/gems/gems/jekyll-3.9.0/lib/jekyll/utils.rb:146:in `initialize': No such device or address @ rb_sysopen - /home/username/GS/dev/ElectricRCAircraftGuy.github.io/127.0.0.1 (Errno::ENXIO)
```

So, oddly enough, my solution was to delete that `127.0.0.1` file:

```
rm 127.0.0.1
```

Fixed!

Now, this works just fine:

```
bundle exec jekyll serve --livereload --drafts --unpublished
```